# How to get value from a v-for loop in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js

I need to access data from a v-for loop in a Vue template. I can't figure out how though..
This is what I have so far:

```
Vue.component('artikel-lista', {
  template:`
  <ul>
  <artikel v-for="artikel in artiklar">{{ artikel.title }} Pris: {{artikel.price}} <a :href="artikel.link" target="_blank" class="button tiny">Läs mer</a></artikel>
  </ul>
  `,
  data(){
    return{
      artiklar: App.artiklar
    }
  },

  created(){
    Event.$on('isSelected', function() {
      // here I need to access for example artikel.title from the v-for loop
    });
  },

});
```

The event listener Event.$on() is receiving an event (that part works). When this happens I want to get the value from for example artikel.title in the v-for loop. How can I do that?

EDITED:
Some more info about the problem... I have a list of items, each preceded by a checkbox. I need to get the values from the checked li elements. So I emit an event when the checkbox is clicked in one Vue component, and listen for the event in another Vue component, where I would like to fetch the current 'artikel' value and store it.

I realize now that need to rethink this and instead see which checkboxes are checked when clicking a 'submit' button (Add items) and not when the checkbox is clicked.
But the problem of getting values from the v-for loop outside of the loop remains I think...

This is the other Vue Component (that sends the event):

```
Vue.component('artikel',{
  template: '<li style="list-style-type:none;"><input @change="isSelected" type="checkbox" class="kryssruta" /><slot></slot></li>',

  methods:{
    isSelected(){
      Event.$emit('isSelected');
    },
  }

});
```

The first line of code is this:

```
window.Event = new Vue();
```

So that I can send events between components using "Event".

The custom element `<artikel-lista></artikel-lista>` is used in a third Vue component. The result is a list of items with a checkbox in front of each list item.

Comment: I think you can pass an argument to your function like `Event.$on('isSelected', function(args) { // check the args value... }` which would contain the information you need. If not, then would you be able to post where the isSelected function is defined in your code?

Comment: Without knowing what fires the `isSelected` event, and how the code looks like - or at least some description - it is difficult to help. It would also be good if you could elaborate a bit what your intentions are. Using global Events are often times a result of misunderstanding the concepts of Vue. There is probably a more elegant solution to this :-)

Comment: If the `artikel` component is what is emitting the event, you should listen directly on that. Then you could do something like this `<artikel @isSelected="myFunction(artikel)" />` where `myFunction` is the method you call when `isSelected` is emitted. That way you're passing the `artikel` that was selected into your callback.

Comment: Matthias S: I elaborated a bit more about my problem, see my edited question. Angelo: it turns out that "args" contains "undefined" in this case.